# AWS amplify not rendering image using the dynamic online url while local build render image correctly

Tags: vuejs3, aws-amplify

Locally I got:
[image]

The deployed version I got:
[image]

I'm not sure why the service URL is added before the image URL.
And the wired thing is the dynamic url path does not load correctly while the static path works well.
[image]

I guess it might have to do with the path redirection so below is my setting:
[image]

Comment: Can you take the url of the image, and paste it into an incognito window? Does it show then?